# Integral basis for an ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

This is something I was curious about from 
my algebraic number theory class.
Given any non-zero ideal $I$ of $A \cap K$
(algebraic integers in $K$ where $[K:\mathbb{Q}] < \infty$),
we know it has an integral basis $\{\alpha_1,..., \alpha_n \}$
such that every element in $I$ can be uniquely written as
a integral linear combination of $\{ \alpha_1,..., \alpha_n \}$.

Does it follow that $I$ is in fact $Span_{\mathbb{Z}} (\alpha_1,..., \alpha_n)$?
(If not, when is this true?)

Here $\mathbb{Q}$ is rationals and $\mathbb{Z}$ is integers...
Thanks!

Comment: It's true. Your "can be written as a integral linear combination" line is exactly why.

Comment: I'm a little confused by your definition $A\cap K$, if $[K:\mathbb{Q}] < \infty$ then $K$ is an algebraic number field, and therefore it's elements are already algebraic!
Maybe you meant algebraic integers?

Comment: @AlexJBest Yes, let me fix that.

Comment: @Sanchez I am still not quite sure... because the existence of integral basis gives that every element in $I$ can be written as an integral linear combination of $\alpha_i$'s. Could you possibly explain how it follow that $I$ must contain all integral linear combination of $\alpha_i$'s?

Comment: @Tom Mosher, when you say integral basis, I suppose you mean integral basis of $I$. In that case, all the $\alpha_i$ lie in $I$, and we know that $I$ is closed under addition..

Comment: The fact that everything in $I$ can be written as linear combinations of $\alpha_i$s tells you $I\subseteq{\rm Span}_{\bf Z}\{\alpha_i\}$. The fact that each $\alpha_i$ is in $I$ tells us that $I\supseteq{\rm Span}_{\bf Z}\{\alpha_i\}$. Since we have inclusion in both directions, we have equality $I={\rm Span}_{\bf Z}\{\alpha_i\}$.

Comment: I get it now! Thanks you!!!

Comment: Amusing side fact: every ideal in a ring of integers can be generated (over the ring, not over $\mathbb{Z}$) by at most two elements.  This is actually true in any Dedekind domain.